# How do I set margins on the DD MM or YYYY fields within an SWT DateTime widget?

Tags: java, datetime, swt, datetimepicker

I am using an instance of a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime` widget for letting the user set a date in the UI, but I'm having issues properly setting margins and styles on the result. I am using `SWT.DATE` and `SWT.DROP_DOWN` and get everything I need from the widget out of the box, which is great, but how do I get the text within the input to have margins so it doesn't start right on the edge of the input box?

Alternatively, can I set a padding within the DateTime inner composite somehow? I have tried the usual, but have only succeeded in setting a margin on the Composite itself...

Right now, it looks like this:

[image: Image of my current situation, no margin]

Instantiated with this code:

```
    (...)
    dateInputComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.LEFT);

    Label datumLabel = new Label(dateInputComposite, SWT.LEFT);
    dateLabel.setText(DATE_LABEL_TEXT);
    dateLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER | GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL));

    DateTime dateInputWidgetWidget = new DateTime(dateInputComposite, SWT.DATE | SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    // create bindings for dateInputWidgetWidget  here

    new DateTime(dateInputComposite, SWT.DATE | SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().margins(0, 0).numColumns(3).applyTo(dateInputComposite);
```

Comment: Layout always adjusts the space around a control, never the spacing in the control.

Comment: @greg-449 I see. Does that mean it's as easy as that if there isn't an API to adjust it through the DateTime widget itself then it isn't possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using [Nebula's `CDateTime`](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php), then you can define your own pattern and set it to something like: `" dd/MM/yyyy"` (mind the space character at the start) to add some artificial margin/padding.

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    CDateTime dateTime = new CDateTime(shell, CDT.DATE_MEDIUM | CDT.DROP_DOWN);
    dateTime.setPattern(" dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateTime.setSelection(new Date());

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Or add padding around each component by using `" dd / MM / yyyy "`:

[image]

Comment: I am, of course, a little disappointed that I'll need a new dependency for something that sounded so simple to me - and that the new dependency only has support for it through a dateformat hack... But I appreciate the help a lot - and I will use this solution if none other pops up!

Comment: @Spork I felt the same. You can't even specify the format of the regular `DateTime`. It'll use your OS's settings which makes proper i18n very difficult, e.g. if a users OS is set to German, but they want the application to be in English. `CDateTime` is a good alternative, but yes, it adds another dependency.